# pip installed in wrong location

Tags: python, pip

I went to install a bunch of stuff using pip (which I had not used in awhile) and I get a message telling me I should upgrade my version of pip. I tried a few things, and then came across [this doc](http://pip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/#install-pip), which I followed with no problem.

But, when I tried to use pip, as in `pip show pyserial' I got an error:

```
$ pip show pyserial
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

and I then discovered pip is not installed there...

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

any way to install in the correct place, or point the pip command to /usr/local/bin/pip?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the directory `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH` variable. If it isn't, then add this line to your `.bash_profile` in your home directory:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`